# Приземлился? Прикометился?

Tags: терминология

Из актуального.
Спускаемый аппарат совершил посадку на поверхность кометы.
***Он приземлился? Прикометился?*** 
Слово "прилунился" есть даже в словарях, но этим дело и ограничивается. Сдается мне, что даже оно (образование по типу "приземлился") не совсем верно. Тут ведь речь идет не столько о Земле-планете, сколько о поверхности-грунте: сравните "приводнился" - тоже словарное.

Comment: А если серьезно?

Comment: >> Из актуального. Спускаемый аппарат совершил посадку на поверхность кометы.

Из актуального?!

Comment: Ну да. Новсти слушаете иногда?

Comment: Почти никогда. И кто же там прикометился?

Comment: "Филя" с "Розетты". На комету Р67/Чурюмова-Герасименко.
http://slon.ru/fast/future/spuskaemyy-apparat-fily-sovershil-pervuyu-v-istorii-posadku-na-kometu-1183515.xhtml

Comment: Ах! ренеть. Правда не читал. Но все равно, слово, думаю, изобретать рановато. )))

Answer (score 1):

> Тут ведь речь идет не столько о Земле-планете, сколько о поверхности-грунте: сравните "приводнился" - тоже словарное.

Там, на комете, кто его знает, что за поверхность... Может быть вообще лёд. Да ещё и, возможно, лёд не из воды, а из замёрзших газов. Так что для таких неопределённых случаев предлагаю вариант: 
*"Аппарат достиг поверхности (кометы, Марса, Юпитера и т.п.)"*

Comment: Увы, это не совсем то. Идея-то, что нет приемлемого варианта сказать одним словом, правильная, но, увы, "достиг поверхности" и "совершил посадку" - далеко не одно и тоже с технической точки зрения. Под "достиг поверхности" традиционно понимают, что аппарат разбился. Раньше еще уточняли, что посадка - она "мягкая", теперь это считают излишним.    
Так что, похоже, остается только "совершил посадку на поверхность".

Answer (score 1):

Слово прилуниться возникло как неологизм в советскую эпоху, когда Русские приземлились на луну. Слово "прокометиться" еще не изобрели. Видимо потому, что это событие еще не вызвало столь громкой сенсации, как приземление на луну. Возможно, когда событие станет известным, о нем заговорят, появится и само слово. А пока остается, как вы сами отметили, "совершил посадку на комету". Хотя в статье используется глагол "приземлиться", что считаю лексической ошибкой.

Comment: Ну это в одной статье. )))   
Я не стал бы спрашивать не услышав.    
Насчет лексической ошибки - не уверен.   
Как уже сказал, ошибка скорее в том, что "приземлился" воспринимается как имеющее отношение к земле-планете.   
Ср. "приводнился".   
В английском - "to land", никак не Earth.

Comment: Но ведь комета не есть земля-планета, поэтому лексическая  ошибка. В английском Earth.-земля в смысле земной шар. Поэтому to land.